# Prove that the number of prime factors of an integer n greater than 1 is at most log$_2$(n).

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove that the number of prime factors of an integer n greater than 1 is at most log$_2$(n). For example 28 = 2 x 2 x 7 has 3 prime factors, and 3 < log$_2$28 = 4.80735.

Answer (score 3):

We get equality when $n=2^k$. In that case, $n$ has $k$ prime factors (each of which is the number $2$), and $\log_2{n}=k$.

If $n\neq2^k$, then $n$ has at least one prime factor other than $2$.

Let the prime factorization be $n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot ... \cdot p_k$.

Then $\log_2{n}=\log_2{p_1}+\log_2{p_2}+ ...+\log_2{p_k}$.

On the right side, any term in which the prime factor is $2$ has a value of $1$. Since at least one prime factor is greater than $2$, at least one of the terms is greater than $1$, and thus the sum of the terms on the right side is greater than $k$.

Therefore, $\log_2{n}$ is equal to something greater than $k$, or equivalently $k<\log_2{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

You take the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$. Then it has a sequence of subgroups $G>G_1>...G_{k+1}=\{1\}$ such that $[G_i:G_{i+1}]$ is a prime and $k$ is equal to the number of prime divisors. Since each of these indices is at least $2$, we have $2^k\le n$. So $k\le \log_2 n$.

Answer (score 1):

The prime factorization of $n$ is a product of a bunch of prime factors which are greater than or equal to $2$, so if there are $k$ of them, we know that $n\ge2^k$. This is equivalent to $k\le\log_2n$.